# Contents of sheet music songbooks

Tags: data-request, music

I want to use a software (excel?) to get my sheet music organized.

But typing in all songs of all books by hand is annoying and error prone.

I am interested in all kind of data about the songbook and the pieces, e.g.

- song title
- composer
- publisher
- date published
- page number
- isbn number of songbook

Unfortunately the information shown on amazon.com or on the
publisher's websites are not enough (e.g. page number 
is missing most of the times).

How can I get this kind of information?

Does anybody have such lists in structured form?

Comment: Try scraping http://imslp.org/ or http://www.alfred.com/ (see their robots.txt and ToS).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But these are mostly classical pieces. Modern pieces from musicals, jazz, rock, pop, folk songs or comtemporary chart music are not listed there. Maybe they could be provided from the publishers directly? And scraping is not just a lot of work, I don't know if this is against their terms of service.